# Unable to retain transparency using ImageMagick's composite

Tags: imagemagick, transparency, minimagick

I have two images (both png) with transparency. I am using the [MiniMagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) gem to crop two copies of a single image into two other images. I'm then wanting to compose one of these images on top of the other, retaining the transparency all the way down.

Using the following code, it is respecting the transparency of image2, but once it is placed on top of image1 (which is what I'm after), the transparency of image1 is changed to black! I need to retain the transparency, but I'm really not sure how to properly use the alpha transparency stuff, if that is even the proper tool here.

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open("skin.png")
image1 = MiniMagick::Image.open(image.path)
image2 = MiniMagick::Image.open(image.path)

# Crop and scale image1
MiniMagick::Tool::Mogrify.new do |m|
  m.crop '8x8+8+8'
  m.scale '144x144'
  m.background 'transparent'
  m.extent '160x160-8-8'
  m << image1.path
end

# Crop and scale image2
MiniMagick::Tool::Mogrify.new do |m|
  m.crop '8x8+40+8'
  m.scale '160x160'
  m << image2.path
end

result = image1.composite(image2) do |c|
  c.compose 'Over'
  c.alpha 'On'
end

result.write "public/skins/#{profile}.png"

send_file "public/skins/#{profile}.png"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MiniMagick's composite is processed as jpg with initial value.

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/probablycorey/mini_magick/MiniMagick/Image#composite-instance_method

The code below is working for me.

```
result = image1.composite(image2, 'png') do |c|
  c.channel "A"
  c.alpha 'Activate'
  c.compose 'Over'
end
```